# How should I mention that I have collected the data set used in my research myself

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning

This is a sentence from the abstract of my dissertation:

> We conduct our research on X-ray images collected by the researcher under the supervision of an expert physician.

Does it sound okay? How would you improve it? I want to mention somehow that I have collected the images myself.

Also, can I use the plural word "We" along with the singular "the researcher"?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would change it a bit.

> We **conducted/are conducting** our research on X-ray images collected by the researcher, under the supervision of an expert physician.

If "our research" is currently in progress, you should use present perfect to indicate that. If "our research" has already been completed, then past tense is fine.

As I read the example, "our research" is a separate activity from "X-ray images collected by the researcher", and not necessarily done by the same person(s). So as written it may be OK depending on context.

I added the comma to break up the sentence as it is long.
But also as written the phrase "under the supervision of an expert physician" is assumed to refer to the "researcher". The phrase should be reordered if it refers to "our research".

Comment: The sentence is ambiguous even with the comma about whether the research is being conducted under the supervision of a physician, or just the collection of the images. "We conducted research on images which were collected under the supervision of a physician by our researcher." or "Under the supervision of of a physician, we conducted research on x-ray images we collected.

Comment: @ColleenV Your first sentence is true (It's only the collection of images that has been done with the physician). But your sentence doesn't mention that I was the collector.

Comment: @user3169 Thanks for the point about the past tense. And yes, the collection of images is a separate activity but it is also done by me (under the supervision of the physician).

Comment: "but it is also done by *me*" but there is no "me" in your sentence. And it is not specified who the "researcher" is.

Comment: @mrmashal I wasn't attempting to answer. I was giving examples of sentences that weren't ambiguous to show the two different ways your sentence could be interpreted.

Comment: @user3169 I thought it is obvious: It is my dissertation and everything is done by me.

Comment: Then why use "we"?